# Notepad++ RegEx: Search two words in subsequent lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

Consider the following text

```
-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2
    xfsCDMStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX SEQUENCE OF XfsCDMStatusEntry
        MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
        STATUS current
        DESCRIPTION
            "Define the set of MIB Variables for the CDM status table."
        ::= { xfsCDMV1 2 }


    -- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2.1
    xfsCDMStatusEntry OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX XfsCDMStatusEntry
        MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
        STATUS current
```

Need to filter lines which contains "1.3.6.1.4.1.16213" in first line and "OBJECT-TYPE" in next line.

Output like

```
 -- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2
    xfsCDMStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
 -- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2.1
    xfsCDMStatusEntry OBJECT-TYPE
```

Can someone help with Regex pattern.

Comment: I believe you can only do that like this: use `(?s).*?\h*([^\n]*1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.16213[^\n]*\R[^\n]*OBJECT-TYPE[^\n]*)` regex and `$1` replacement to remove what is before the lines you want, and then manually remove what remains at the end. Or use a second regex replacement: `(?s)(OBJECT-TYPE[^\n]*)(?:(?!OBJECT-TYPE).)*\z` => `$1`.

Comment: @stribizhev Hi thanks for your comment, it outputs only second line and skips version.

Comment: I have `-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2
    xfsCDMStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2.1
    xfsCDMStatusEntry OBJECT-TYPE` with the "tail" after the first replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Try this expression:

```
(?-s)^(?:(?:(?!.*?\R+.*?\bOBJECT-TYPE\b).*?$(?:\R+|$))|(^.*?\R+.*?\bOBJECT-TYPE\b.*?$))
```

Replace with `$1`

It will take an input like this:

```
-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2
xfsCDMStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX SEQUENCE OF XfsCDMStatusEntry
    MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Define the set of MIB Variables for the CDM status table."
    ::= { xfsCDMV1 2 }


-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2.1
xfsCDMStatusEntry OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX XfsCDMStatusEntry
    MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
    STATUS current


-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2
xfsCDMStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX SEQUENCE OF XfsCDMStatusEntry
    MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Define the set of MIB Variables for the CDM status table."
    ::= { xfsCDMV1 2 }
```

and output the following:

```
-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2
xfsCDMStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2.1
xfsCDMStatusEntry OBJECT-TYPE
-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2
xfsCDMStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
```

If you'd like to only specify the lines that have the value `1.3.6.1.4.1.16213` then use the following:

```
(?-s)^(?:(?:(?!.*?1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.16213.*?\R+.*?\bOBJECT-TYPE\b).*?$(?:\R+|$))|(^.*?\R+.*?\bOBJECT-TYPE\b.*?$))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but since large file it didnt find the txt

Comment: @vels4j How large is the text file?

Comment: @vels4j I've tried this with a text file that is about 8MB containing 420 hits and it still works as expected.

Comment: @vels4j Sorry about that! had set it to `(?s)` single line mode when I meant `(?-s)` not single line mode

Comment: This will keep lines that begin with `2.3.6.1.4.1.16213` that is not wanted.

Comment: @Toto - updated answer - given the examples I didn't think it was a required.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

- Find what: `(\-\- 1\.3\.6\.1\.4\.1\.16213\b[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+[^\r\n]*OBJECT-TYPE[^\r\n]*)([\r\n]+ [^\r\n]*)*[\r\n]*`
- Replace with: `$1\n`
- "Regular expression" checked
- ". matches newline" unchecked

Content example:

```
-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2
xfsCDMStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX SEQUENCE OF XfsCDMStatusEntry
    MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Define the set of MIB Variables for the CDM status table."
    ::= { xfsCDMV1 2 }


-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2.1
xfsCDMStatusEntry OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX XfsCDMStatusEntry
    MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
    STATUS current


-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2
xfsCDMStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX SEQUENCE OF XfsCDMStatusEntry
    MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Define the set of MIB Variables for the CDM status table."
    ::= { xfsCDMV1 2 }


-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.xxxxx.2.3.1.2
xfsCDMStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX SEQUENCE OF XfsCDMStatusEntry
    MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Define the set of MIB Variables for the CDM status table."
    ::= { xfsCDMV1 2 }
```

After [Replace All]:

```
-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2
xfsCDMStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2.1
xfsCDMStatusEntry OBJECT-TYPE
-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.16213.2.3.1.2
xfsCDMStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
-- 1.3.6.1.4.1.xxxxx.2.3.1.2
xfsCDMStatusTable OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX SEQUENCE OF XfsCDMStatusEntry
    MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Define the set of MIB Variables for the CDM status table."
    ::= { xfsCDMV1 2 }
```

Comment: @vels4j: Does that fit your needs? Any question?